# Platform.getBundle method missing in SWT 4.2

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying the use the snippet shown [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#specifyxulrunner) but method `getBundle()` for class `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` seems not to be defied in SWT 4.2.
Did they move/remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The `Platform` class is not part of SWT, it is part of the Eclipse Core Runtime. You might have to add `org.eclipse.core.runtime` to the dependencies of your plugin/fragment.

Hope this helps